# GridView not scrolling to top on item delete

Tags: android, gridview, scroll, android-adapter

I am trying to implement a functionality that I have multiple images in my gridview. If I delete say top 5-6 records, I want the gridview to refresh and set scroll position to top. I used `notifyDataSetChanged()`. However the list does refresh but scroll position does not move to top. How do I do it? I have used a custom Adapter.

Comment: You may have to post some relevant codes

Comment: did you try `gridView.setSelection(0);`?

Answer (score 2):

After you are done with deleting the images and you called `notifyDataSetChanged()` call

```
gridview.smoothScrollToPosition(0); // forces gridview to scroll to first position
```

or

```
gridView.setSelection(0);
```